# jquery: read value from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

following is the json array I am trying to read in jquery:

```
[
    "value1",
    "value2"
]
```

Jquery code:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data); //data is the above json string
for(s in obj)
    alert(s);
```

but it alerts 0 and 1,while I want it to alert "value1" and "value2".How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do:

```
for(s in obj)
    alert(obj[s]);
```